# Is there a way to download my dashboard as is in a pdf file

Tags: r, pdf, shiny, download

I have tried to download my application dashboard in png with the screenshot() function but some of the charts and texts are a little blurred.

Ideally I want to be able to download the dashboard texts and charts as is in a pdf file.

This is the link to my application:
https://iecprojects.shinyapps.io/CountryProfile1/

Is there any way I can achieve this? Any idea or example can help.

Comment: Really impressive dashboard!

Comment: Can you just print to PDF in your browser?

Comment: Thank you. Yes i tried to print in PDF from browser. It's not looking nice. The charts are overlapping onto each other.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [screenshot the whole shinydashboard page as pdf by hitting a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70056208/screenshot-the-whole-shinydashboard-page-as-pdf-by-hitting-a-button)

Comment: Thank you. I have tried the Javascript one. This is the first thing I tried but in my application for some reason it does not work. I tried it separately but the image is blurry not high quality. The users need the images to be high quality also. If this Javascript can be modified to make the images high quality I could figure out a way to make it work on the main application.

Comment: I have tried the screenshot() function. See the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73581290/screenshot-function-is-not-working-as-expected  However the function is not working as expected.